# Importing Bootstrap LESS files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

So I'm trying to import the bootstrap button.less file into my own project. However in this case I only want the danger button css stuff to include and the core button classes.

Something along the lines of

```
    .my_custom_button {
    .btn();
    .btn-danger();
    .btn-small();
}
```

But I don't particularly need all the other stuff. e.g. the warning colour class etc. Currently by using:

```
    @import "mixins.less";
    @import "variables.less";
    @import "buttons.less";
```

I'm importing the entire file css into my project - is there any way I can avoid this (I'm a LESS noob) or is this just a consequence of less?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Now Available in LESS 1.5

As of LESS 1.5 you can do an import as just a reference (so you can use the mixins without getting all the code compiled). Like this:

```
@import (reference) "mixins.less";
@import (reference) "variables.less";
@import (reference) "buttons.less";

.my_custom_button {
  .btn();
  .btn-danger();
  .btn-small();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The danger style is just this:

```
.btn-danger {
  .buttonBackground(@btnDangerBackground, @btnDangerBackgroundHighlight);
}
```

So, in short, you don't need the `buttons.less` file.

Comment: But do I still get the padding and size details from the .btn-small() details? I need the other details from my 3 classes

Comment: OK so I can copy the buttons styling accross - but that kind of defeats the objective of using the LESS code - any ideas of how I can avoid that without copying buttons.less?

Comment: If you need other styles, copying them is the way. You cannot import only "a few things from a file": import everything or nothing. This probably applies to all programming languages.

Comment: Feared as much :/ I was hoping by the `.btn-small();` it was more like import the file with the relevant then include the relevent functions rather than including the entire file contents into the css file

Comment: Hey clearly wants to use mixins and other features of LESS.